# Show Hide Issue with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, show-hide

This is my Google Maps code (it works perfectly by itself):

```
<table width=99%>

<tr><td align="center">

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


 var map;

function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude_deg']; ?>,<?php echo $row['longitude_deg']; ?>),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID

  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  map.setTilt(45);

  map.setHeading(90);

}


function autoRotate() {

  // Determine if we're showing aerial imagery

  if (map.getTilt() != 0) {
map.setHeading(180);
setTimeout('map.setHeading(270)',3000);
setTimeout('map.setHeading(0)',6000);
setTimeout('map.setHeading(90)',9000);

  }

}

</script>

<body onload="initialize()">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:350px"></div>

</td></tr></table>
```

Here is my code for my show/hide function:

```
 <div style="background-color:black; width:80%; cursor:pointer;hand" onClick="showhide('id6'); return(false);"><table width="100%"><tr><td width=80% align=left><font color="white" size="4"><strong>&nbsp;Airport Maps</strong></font></td><td align=right><font color="white" size="1"></font></td></tr></table></div>

<span id="id6" style="display: none">    
****Google Maps Code goes here****
</span>
```

I'm having an issue when I put my google map code inside of the "span""/span" where it does not function properly. Google Maps shows up but the imagery says no image available and it's in the wrong place.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: That HTML is horribly invalid (what's `<body>` doing in the middle of `<table>`?). `<span>` is an inline element, not block-level; it *might* work if you change your `<span>` into `<div>` but you need to start with getting the HTML valid. It would also help to provide the definition of your `showhide()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

```
function displayMap() {
                document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display="block";
                initialize();
            }
```

Inside Show All Div:

```
   onClick="showall('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7'); displayMap(); return(false);"
```

Inside Individual Show/Hide Div:

```
   onClick="showhide('id6'); displayMap(); return(false);"
```